# How would I show this is injective, surjective and that this proves that Z (the set of all integers) is denumerable?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Here is what I have been working on.

**Let $g : \mathbb N_0 → \mathbb Z$ be the map defined by $g (x) := (-1)^x \lceil{\frac{x}{2}}\rceil$. Here $\lceil y \rceil$ denotes the least integer greater than the real number $y$.**

In order to show that $g$ is injective any number that I put as $x$ must only map to one $y$, and surjective is that I can have one $y$ being mapped from multiple $x$'s. So should I create a table of say $0$-$5$ and input these numbers as $x$ and record my output?

For the last part I am not sure how I could explain that this is denumerable. Is it because if it is both injective and surjective, that it will work infinitely for all numbers that are given?

Comment: Have a good look at the definitions of *injective* and *surjective*, as these terms have a different meaning than you think.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the value of $g(n)$ for various n. It's not hard to see that

- If $n$ is even ($n=2k$ for some $k\in\mathbb{N}_0$), then $g(n) = g(2k)=(-1)^{2k}\lceil 2k/2\rceil=k=n/2$
- If $n$ is odd ($n=2k+1$), then you can show in a similar way that $g(n)=-(n+1)/2$

Notice that for every even $n$, we have $g(n)\ge 0$ and for every odd $n$ we have $g(n)<0$. It's not hard to show, using the above results, that

- If $z\in\mathbb{Z}$ is greater than or equal to zero, then $g(2z)=z$
- If $z\in\mathbb{Z}$ is less than zero, then $g(-2z-1)=z$

---

To show that $g:\mathbb{N}_0\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}$ is surjective, we need to show that for every $z\in\mathbb{Z}$ there is an $n\in\mathbb{N}_0$ such that $g(n)=z$. Can you do that? Hint: separate into two cases, depending on whether $z$ is negative or not.

---

To show that $g$ is injective we need to show that if $n\ne m$, then $g(n)\ne g(m)$. I'll leave that to you again. As before we have several cases to consider: $n$ is even and $m$ is odd, $n$ is odd and $m$ is even, both $n$ and $m$ are even, and both $n$ and $m$ are odd. Hint: the first two cases are easy.

---

For your last question, you have established that there's a bijection from $\mathbb{N}_0$ to $\mathbb{Z}$ so the two sets have the same cardinality. Since you know that $\mathbb{N}_0$ is denumerable, it must be the case that $\mathbb{Z}$ is also.

Comment: Yes, thank you, I have gotten to the point where I understand the mathematical procedure, but now HOW do I actually write out the proof for this?

Comment: @JoesephG.S. A glib answer would be "Just fill in the few parts that I left for you." For example, how would you complete the part where you show that $g$ is surjective? Pick any $z\in\mathbb{Z}$, then if $z\ge 0$ we'd have $g(2z)=z$ so all the nonnegative integers are the image of some natural. Carry on for the rest.

Answer (score 0):

for your mapping question, look at the cases of even and odd arguments $g(2m)$ and $g(2m+1)$ separately

Comment: Ok so for 0-4 I got this, g(0) = 0, g(1) = -1, g(2) = 1, g(3) = -2 and g(4) = 2. So this would prove that it is injective but does this also prove that it is surjective? Also how would I write this as a proof statement?

Comment: good so far - i would add, 1.take note of Arthur's comment above 2. a few examples are only suggestive, but do not constitute a proof. you have started off well. can you use induction to prove that $\forall m, g(2m)=m$? that would be half of the solution. when the going is tough, establish some definite progress - it builds confidence!

Comment: PS Rick's answer just became visible. that will give you a lot of help

Comment: Ok, I have gotten to the point where I understand where each is injective and surjective by doing the math, but HOW do I actually write the proof for it?

Answer (score 0):

Joseph, now you have grappled a bit more with the problem, let us formulate it is a slightly different way. not quite to prove anything yet, but to give free reign to our intuition about what is happening.

let $L$ denote the negative integers, and $R$ denote the non-negative integers. then $L$ and $R$ form a  *disjoint decomposition* of $Z$, the set of all integers. (L=left, R=right)
this means:
$$ 
L \cup R = Z \\
L \cap R = \emptyset
$$

similarly let $E$ denote the even natural numbers $0,2,4,6,\dots$ and let $O$ denote the odd natural numbers, so that $O$ and  $E$ are a disjoint decomposition of $N_0$, the whole set of natural numbers $0,1,2,3,\dots$

$$ 
O \cup E = N_0 \\
O \cap E = \emptyset
$$

we map $R$ to $E$ by the function $\phi: n \rightarrow 2n$. it is clear that this map is injective and surjective. it is one direction of a *bijection*. moreover, we can easily define the other direction of this bijection, because every element of  $E$ is even, there is an inverse map $\phi^{-1}:E \rightarrow R$ which is simply division by $2$.

we map $L$ to $O$ with the function $\psi: -n \rightarrow 2n-1$. it is harder to visualize this map, but not really difficult to see that $\psi$ is also a bijection. the reverse direction for this bijection, $\psi^{-1}$ is the most complex operation as we have to perform three operations in succession. first add $1$, making the number even, secondly we must divide by $2$, and finally we must multiply by minus one. in fact, for a number $k \in O$:
$$
\psi^{-1}(k) = - \phi^{-1}(k+1)
$$

so we have two bijections, 
$$
E \rightarrow^{\phi} R  \rightarrow^{\phi^{-1}} E
$$
and
$$
L \rightarrow^{\psi} O  \rightarrow^{\psi^{-1}} L
$$
you can probably see that these bijections between the elements of the disjoint decompositions combine to give a bijection between the full sets $N_0$ and $Z$